# Python Challenge - Level 5 , almost there

Tags: list, python-3.x

i am in level 5 now, i think that exmaple of whare i am stuck is the best here,
the pickle content is:

```
[(' ', 95)]
[(' ', 14), ('#', 5), (' ', 70), ('#', 5), (' ', 1)]
[(' ', 15), ('#', 4), (' ', 71), ('#', 4), (' ', 1)]
[(' ', 15), ('#', 4), (' ', 71), ('#', 4), (' ', 1)]
[(' ', 15), ('#', 4), (' ', 71), ('#', 4), (' ', 1)]
[(' ', 15), ('#', 4), (' ', 71), ('#', 4), (' ', 1)]
[(' ', 15), ('#', 4), (' ', 71), ('#', 4), (' ', 1)]
[(' ', 15), ('#', 4), (' ', 71), ('#', 4), (' ', 1)]
[(' ', 15), ('#', 4), (' ', 71), ('#', 4), (' ', 1)]
```

it is much longer that that though.
and my code right now is:

```
!#/usr/bin/python3
import pickle
with open("/home/hanan/Downloads/banner.p", 'rb') as file:
file = pickle.load(file)
for line in file:
    for each_item in line:
        print(each_item[0]*each_item[1], end='')
```

what i want to do (as i have understand it is the solution to the problem), is to print each sign (e.g '' or #) times the number after it, so ('#', 5) the # sign would be print like that ##### .

i am prefer to see what is wrong with my current code, and in case you have other way to solve that i would be glad to see it.

Edit: After some thinking, i see here that the pickle file is actually contain a list of lists and inside each of the second lists (the line the the code above) there is items (each_item) which they tuple type (basically they are like lists but can't be changed), hence the each_item[x] (x = number).

BTW: as you can see i am using python 3.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't printing any new lines at the end of each line.

Try this instead:

```
for line in file:
    print(''.join(c * n for c, n in line))
```

Or alternatively, just add a call to `print` in your existing code:

```
for line in file:
    for each_item in line:
        print(each_item[0]*each_item[1], end='')
    print()
```

Comment: Thanks it is working, i would like to know what i was wrong, why have you add the print() ?

Comment: OK, i have got that. Thanks again.

Comment: One thing though i am struggle to understand, this is a list of lists an so whem i am have the each_item variable at the above code which is the second list, the i am print the each_item[0], and here i am struggle to understand, why is the 0 at the end of the gave me the character, in other words is the each_item var9able at the above code is a list too? Because if it is, it the pickle file actully contain 3 lists and not two, and how is the 3rd list is set without [ ] notation. Hope you understand my question. Thanks.